# Why store load event don't work?

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a simple example :

```
var store =  Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {

})
store.load();
store.on('load', function() {
    alert('test');
})
```

Why is it not work ?

Comment: Why would you need `load` on an ArrayStore? It should load without calling `store.load()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're performing the load() before you add the listener.  Put the store.load() after the on() call.

Edit:  Yes, I tested it.